# SQL Server Update Fails Based on Another Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

In SQL Server 2012, I am trying to set the values of my "TradeDate" column equal to the values of my "MARKET_DAY" column. Here is my current code:

```
USE Sales
GO
update dbo.try1
SET dbo.try1.TradeDate = dbo.yesterday.MARKET_DAY
FROM dbo.try1, dbo.yesterday
```

However, when I run this, I get:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

and I do not know why. Any help is greatly appreciated. (I am a noob in T-SQL, be gentle, please.)

Comment: What is the condition? How many rows you have in `dbo.try1` and how many of them in `dbo.yesterday`? Could you give us an example how you want to update data in `dbo.try1` from `dbo.yesterday`

Comment: `dbo.try1` has no data in its `TradeDate` column. I am trying to copy the data from `dbo.yesterday`'s `MARKET_DAY` column to `dbo.try1`'s `TradeDate` column. This may be bad db design, but it is necessary for the task at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to Insert data from "yesterday" table to "try1"?

```
INSERT INTO try1(TradeDate)
SELECT MARKET_DAY FROM yesterday
--You can mention your condition, if anything specific here.
```

Comment: We have a winner! Works perfectly. Out of curiosity, do you know why the `UPDATE` syntax was not working?

Comment: UPDATE is used for "Updating" existing rows.
Ex: If you had TradeDate data X and you wanted to update its value using the value of "yesterday" Y, then you could have used UPDATE SET tradedate=marketday where tradedate=X and marketday=Y

Comment: Now I know. Makes sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: But you have to make sure to avoid duplication entries. If you execute the query N times, the all the data from MARKEY_DAY happily gets inserted into try1.

Answer (score 2):

What your above query will do, it will updated each row's column value with same result. I think you want it to be updated your corresponding MARKET_DAY value to corresponding TradeDate column. In that case you need to use `JOIN` operator with common `column`

```
USE Sales
GO
update dbo.try1
SET dbo.try1.TradeDate = dbo.yesterday.MARKET_DAY
FROM dbo.try1 INNER JOIN dbo.yesterday
ON dbo.try1.columnName=dbo.yesterday.columnName
```

Comment: on which column have you specified `Inner join` ?

Comment: I think your question was related to update the column. if it was the case of insert than why didn't you specified in your question?

Comment: Because I did not understand the nature of `UPDATE` vs. `INSERT`. Apologies for the ambiguity, I can see your reply answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

that would be really helpful if you could show us your Tables design but so far this is what I guess:

the entities you are trying to update must be something in common otherwise the update won't work properly !

here is an example :

`dbo.try1` :

[image]

`dbo.yesterday` :

[image]

and here is the query :

```
USE DBTest
GO
update dbo.try1
SET dbo.try1.TradeDate = dbo.yesterday.MARKET_DAY
FROM dbo.try1 INNER JOIN dbo.yesterday
ON dbo.try1.id=dbo.yesterday.id
```

in this case the entities in both tables have a common id so I was able to update them based on their ids .

here's the result of executing the query above :

[image]